# Scraping multiple pages in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the pages in this website: https://www.edison.k12.nj.us/directory?const_page=1&. I thought that I could go to the next page by replacing the number 1 with 2,3,4 and so on. However, this was not the case because when I checked href attribute of the  tags, it doesn't seem to link to a new page. In this case, how can I scrape multiple pages in this case? Thank you so much!

```
page = 1
df_list = []
df = None
while(page < 240):
    url = 'https://www.edison.k12.nj.us/directory?const_page='+str(page)+'&amp;'
    # gets back the beautiful soup object
    bs = create_beautiful(url)

    #calls the extract_data to get necessary data()
    df2 = extract_data(bs)
    if page == 1:
        df = df2
        
    else:
        df_list.append(df2)
        

    page+=1

count = 1
for df2 in df_list:
    df.append(df2 , ignore_index = True)
    count+=1

to_csv_and_excel(df, 'edison_township_public')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see if any requests are being sent from the server or to the server in the dev tools -> network -> Fetch/XHR tab. Try to click on the next page and you'll this link in the *headers* tab:

```
https://www.edison.k12.nj.us/fs/elements/59?const_page=1&is_draft=false&is_load_more=true&parent_id=59&_=1629643598511
```

You can try to do a very basic `for` in `range()` loop and replace `const_page={VALUE}` and `parent_id=59&_=162964359851{VALUE}` with loop values.

*Note: it is slow and needs to be replaced with a faster solution if needed.*

```py
for index in range(1, 240):

  params = {
    'const_page': index, 
    'is_draft': 'false',
    'is_load_more': 'true',
    'parent_id': '59',
    '_': f'162964359851{index}' # only LAST number changing on each page. Same as const_page number.
    
  }
  
  html = requests.get(f"https://www.edison.k12.nj.us/fs/elements/59", params=params)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  title = soup.select_one('.fsConstituentProfileLink').text

--------
'''
Donna Abatemarco 
Irina Acha 
Philip Adornato 
Victoria Ajijedidun 
Taylor Aljian 
Kelly Amabile 
Elizabeth Andrade 
Deliane Antonio 
Nicole Aravena 
Pamela Aurilio 
Aimee Baer 
Sharmila Balaji 
Meghan Banach 
... more names
'''
```